# In Go, how to track down which import is causing an error which occurs upon variable initialization?

Tags: go, go-modules, variable-initialization

I am trying to run the `main()` function for a repository but am running into an intractable panic which occurs upon variable initialization:

```
> go run main.go
go: finding github.com/myorg/some-repo/emulator latest
go: finding github.com/myorg/some-repo latest
panic: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus.(*Registry).MustRegister(0xc0002a09b0, 0xc00033a1d0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.5.1/prometheus/registry.go:400 +0xad
github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promauto.Factory.NewGaugeVec(0x1acee40, 0xc0002a09b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x19ade0e, 0x21, 0x19c60fa, 0x56, ...)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.5.1/prometheus/promauto/auto.go:306 +0x118
github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promauto.NewGaugeVec(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x19ade0e, 0x21, 0x19c60fa, 0x56, 0x0, 0xc000370160, ...)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.5.1/prometheus/promauto/auto.go:197 +0xa9
github.com/myorg/some-library/pubsub.init.ializers()
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/myorg/some-library@v0.0.0-20200404213659-0e93c264015a/pubsub/gcp.go:30 +0xcd
exit status 2
```

The error boils down to this line of code:

```
var inFlightMetric     = promauto.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{Name: "gcp_pubsub_handlers_running_count"})
```

What I believe the problem is, is that that same library also has a `pubsub/v2/gcp.go` which the same line, so programs trying to import both `github.com/myorg/some-library/pubsub` and `github.com/myorg/some-library/pubsub/v2` run into a panic caused by a 'name collision' in the Prometheus metrics collectors.

What I would like to do find which dependency is importing `github.com/myorg/some-library/pubsub` and replace it with `pubsub/v2` to avoid this name collision. I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine that from this stack trace, however. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: `go mod why` and `go mod graph` help you track dependencies.

Comment: The problem is not using different dependencies, but using different *packages* within the same dependency - that is, the code is such that one cannot import both the `pubsub/v2` and `pubsub` packages. I would like to find out where (indirectly) the `pubsub` package is being imported, and as far as I can tell `go mod graph` doesn't provide that information?

Comment: 1. Packages do not carry versions, only modules do. 2. go mod why and graph show why, how which package is imported and you can run in on both packages which collide to see who imports which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this problem by making a branch `avoid-registering-duplicate-metrics-collector` in the library module and importing it from that branch:

```
go get github.com/myorg/some-lib@avoid-registering-duplicate-metrics-collector
```

In that branch, I attached a `_v1` suffix to all the metrics registered in the `pubsub` package to avoid name collisions with the `pusub/v2` ones. This is a bit of a hack though and requires regular merging of the master branch into that branch to keep it up-to-date. A way to find out which file in the imports was actually trying to import the `pubsub` package would still be useful.